# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'ApplicationUser.XXX' of type 'XXX'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am using .NET Core 6 C# MVC application.

My classes are below:

ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]        
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]       
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Photo")]
        public string? ProfilePic { get; set; }       

        
        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }            

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{FirstName + " " + LastName}";
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Choose Profile Image")]
        public IFormFile ChooseProfilePic { get; set; }
    }
```

Company

```
public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Company Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }       
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }        
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }        
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I am going to add migration it shows following error.

**System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'ApplicationUser.Company' of type 'Company'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

See this [image](https://i.imgur.com/Z3S3CYZ.jpg)

I already specified **[ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]** but still getting this issue.

Comment: Should not it be `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` ?

Comment: You can see error in bold text it's clearly say ApplicationUser.Company

Comment: It's not about error but what you should use as base for your context.

Comment: I am not getting you. Please share example.